# How to getBackground() in constructor of CursorAdapter while parent View is absent in it?

Tags: android

I need to get `background` (`Drawable`) which is defined for my `layout` created to be an `item` of my `ListView`. The requirement is to do this in my `Adapter` constructor, but I lack parent `Viewgroup` to `inflate` it. Any other ways to do it?

```
private class MAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        private Drawable defaultDrawable;

        public MAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
            super(context, c, autoRequery);
            this.defaultDrawable = // here I need to get Drawable which is defined as background for the view which is going to be used for `View` for the list row item
        }
```